# Using image with text instead of actual text?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website to practice my HTML and CSS skills. If this was a situation where I'd sell a website to a customer, or a site for personal use on the internet, is there any reason to not have the text as a image? I've made a image in Photoshop and then stuck into a  tag, the image is text (can't show you because I don't have 10 rep...) with a designed underline on the header and centred text below the header, 3 columns of the same side by side.

Comment: Didn't get the point. Could you please clarify somehow and by the way it's surely a question not to be asked here.

Comment: Well I got the answer I was looking for from 2 different people :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien But it has only 1 question ...

Comment: @MysticalGoat My bad, should've closed as Opinion Based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It won't reflow to fit the browser
- It won't resize when the font size is increased
- When you zoom the page, the text will pixelate
- It won't show up in search engines
- It won't show up in text browsers
- It won't show up in screen readers
- Links would have to be implemented with an image map
- It will use more bandwidth (so load more slowly)

Comment: Thank you, thank makes sense, never considered it not showing up in screen readers or search engines :) Seems I've got a long way to go after all :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Several reasons:

1. Text within images isn't copyable.
2. Text within images isn't retrievable by search engines.
3. Images are larger and take longer to download than text does.
4. You have no control over the text with CSS if it's within an image.
5. Users who have images disabled or use text-only browsers would not be able to see any text.